# How do I display only active Mercurial-branches in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, branch, eclipse-luna

Recently I switched from Eclipse Kepler to Eclipse Luna.

In Kepler when I opened Team > Switch To... I only saw open/ active branches. 
Now in Luna when I open this dialog I see ALL branches that were ever created in this repository. And that is a lot :(

Also, when I switch to our "default"-branch it says "24 heads" because two years ago there was an incident and someone created that many heads for this branch. The heads are long closed, but my Eclipse-Mercurial-plugin doesn't care. I still thinks that those heads exist, because it ignores the "closed" status of the branches.

I already checked the Preferences and I found no possibility to change the setting for that. Besides, the settings are identical to my Kepler-installation. Also, I have the same Mercurial-plugin ("MercurialEclipse project", 2.1.0.201304290948, com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse) installed in Kepler and Luna. 
(my OS is Xubuntu 14.10)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, there wasn't really a solution for this :) But I want at least to describe what happened.

I was the only one in our team who had that problem. We found out, that when we use our existing workspaces we had no problems. When we did a completely new check-out into a fresh workspace from our Mercurial-server, we had all the problem described above. (That's the reason I was the only one with the problem: When switching the Eclipse-versions I also decided to start a fresh workspace) So we dug further and found out that all branches we had once marked as "closed" had lost this marker. So that's why they all appeared when I opened the switch-to-dialog: the dialog showed correctly all non-closed branches.

We don't know how this could have happened. No one opened all branches on purpose. Perhaps a Mercurial-bug? And the fact that it didn't affect existing check-out made it even more strange.

The short-term solution: I copied an existing workspace from a colleague and happily continued programming. 
But we knew that it would be a problem for anyone who would join our project in future.

So we just switched to git :) 
We were already discussing this for months, like: should we switch? shouldn't we switch? weighting pros and cons. So this bug seemed to be the perfect reason and opportunity to do the switch.

conclusion:
It wasn't an Eclipse-bug, but a Mercurial-bug. And the solution was git :D